# How to select a column with a specific data type in Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

Considering this `FeatureCollection`:

```js
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(null, {x1: 0.1, x2: 10, x3: "a", x4: 1.1}),
  ee.Feature(null, {x1: 0.2, x2: 9, x3: "b", x4: 2.2}),
  ee.Feature(null, {x1: 0.3, x2: 8, x3: "c", x4: 3.3}),
  ee.Feature(null, {x1: 0.4, x2: 7, x3: "d", x4: 4.4}),
  ee.Feature(null, {x1: 0.5, x2: 6, x3: "e", x4: 5.5}),
  ee.Feature(null, {x1: 0.6, x2: 5, x3: "f", x4: 6.6})
]);
```

How do I select only column `x3` based on data type `string`?

I'm not referring to this method: `fc.select("x3")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean you want to know the data type for all the columns and then  select one or more of them based on that type, then you'd need to map over the properties of one of the features or, if the collection has a schema, get it with Describe, and map over that to test the type of each column:

```
var desc = ee.Dictionary(ee.Algorithms.Describe(fc))
var cols = ee.Dictionary(desc.get('columns'))
var stringCols = cols.map(function(k, v) { 
    return ee.Algorithms.If(ee.Algorithms.IsEqual(v, "String"), k, null)
}).keys())
```

Comment: I have completely missed `ee.Algorithms.Describe()`. Functionality like that is something I've been looking for other use-cases. How "expensive" is it - larger tables for example?

Comment: It doesn't descend into collections; it only describes the outermost object.